# MVC Is this business logic and should be moved from the view to a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, business-logic

I am trying to better understand the MVC pattern and separations of concerns, specifically about what constitutes "business logic". I was recently assigned to an existing asp.net mvc 4 project and have never used the MVC pattern before. As I have been familiarizing myself with the project and with MVC in general I found code in a View that looks similar to the following. Basically different lists of links are being generated depending on the mapLayer of the object opening the view (incidentally the original switch statement is nearly 100 lines long). It seems to me that this logic is "business logic" and should be re-factored into a model instead of being left in the view. Am I correct? and why, or why not?

Sample View Code Segment (generic):

```
<ul id="tabsMore">
    @switch (Model.MapLayerId)
    {
    case "LayerID1":
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("linkNameX", new { clientID = Model.Type1Model.clientID })">displayNameX<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
        ...
        break;
    case "LayerID2":
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("linkNameY", new { clientID = Model.Type1Model.clientID })">displayNameY<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
        ...
        if (int.Parse(@Model.ObjectId.Substring(3, 1)) > 3)
        {
          <li><a href="@Url.Action("linkNameZ", new {linkId = Model.ObjectId})">displayNameZ<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
          ...
        }
        ...
        break;
        ...
    case "LayerIDN":
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("linkNameZ", new { clientID = Model.Type2Model.clientID })">displayNameW<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
        ...
        break;
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: `int.Parse(@Model.ObjectId.Substring(3, 1)) > 3` should be in the model.  It also seems a lot of this could be refactored to remove the swtich statement all together.  This might be something you'd post on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ErikPhilips agreed that a lot could be refactored. So clearly the markup for the lists belongs in the view. Just to clarify: most of the cases have non-overlapping lists of links, should the case of which layer be handled in the model?

Comment: I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but since it appears all you need is clientID, linkId, and ObjectId in your current code, it can be refactored into a class with `bool IsLinkId` and `<type> Id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this business logic and should be moved from the view to a model?

Sometimes is really hard to tell, and can be religious from person to person.  When I look at your code, I would say that the logic is not business logic.  That does not mean it is or is not valid.  Take a step back and realize that this logic can be in a controller or a view.  A view with this logic means that you can reuse this model with different logic and get a different view, sometimes that is completely valid.  Other times it should be in the controller so the view can only display what should be displayed.  For instance some programmers want code in the controller to either return a view, partial view or json.  If it's json, it has no logic, so that means whatever is on the other side needs the correct logic (unless it's in the controller, then all of it always matches, there is no choice).

I would prefer the code to look like:

```
<ul id="tabsMore">
  @if (Model.IsLink)
  {
    <li><a href="@Url.Action(Model.LinkAction, new { linkId = Model.ID })">
    @Model.DisplayName<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
  }
  else
  {
    <li><a href="@Url.Action(Model.LinkAction, new { clientID = Model.ID })">
    @Model.DisplayName<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
  }
</ul>
```

or if you are ok with empty parameters:

```
<ul id="tabsMore">
    <li><a href="@Url.Action(Model.LinkAction, 
      new { linkId = Model.LinkID, clientId = Model.ClientId })">
    @Model.DisplayName<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Although this might be impossible for technical reasons or business rules.

Comment: so in that case would it be appropriate to have the controller check the layer and get the appropriate id's and then have the view just print the list of links based on the passed ids?

Comment: I don't know what would be appropriate, I don't know the rules.  I would say I generally create a ViewModel specifically for each view that only contains the absolutely minimum to render a view.

Answer (score 0):

That logic is not business logic as far I can tell from visible code. There is a switch to decide which view element display so clearly is related to view.

For sure It could be simplified as having a 100 lines switch statement smells a little ugly but there is no obvious problem on MVC concern separation. At first sight the logic is on the correct place but I'd invest some time to make it simpler.

Comment: Ok, so while it is ugly code that needs to be refactored, basically it is still appropriate for the view.